# QueryDSL join two level down with two way relationship

Tags: querydsl

I am looking for QueryDSL help.

I have Three tables. 1) Order 2) Details 3) Lines

Order can have multiple details and details can have multiple lines.

So i have in my OrderDO

```
// bi-directional many-to-one association to FociRequestDetail
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "omsOrder")
    private List<FociRequestDetailDO> fociRequestDetails;
```

and in DetailsDO

```
    // bi-directional many-to-one association to FociRequestLine
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fociRequestDetail")
    private List<FociRequestLineDO> fociRequestLines;

@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "OMS_ORDER_ID")
    private OmsOrderDO omsOrder;
```

and in LinesDO

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "REQUEST_DETAIL_ID")
    private FociRequestDetailDO fociRequestDetail;
```

I want to query all details and lines for given orderId=12345

So my result should have one object or OrderDO
OrderDO as it can be one for given OrderId
-- Details DO should be multiple or one based on orderId
---- Lines DO should be multiple or one based on detailId

I tried doing 
    .from(orderDO).join(orderDO.fociRequestDetails, fociRequestDetailDO)
              .where(orderDO.orderId.eq(orderNo));

it gives me two object of OrderDO. Ideally it should return only one object and two details.

Please suggest on how do i achieve this with one object of Order and its child of details and then its child of lines inside details.